# Как удалить существующий файл, название которого пользователь вводит с клавиатуры?

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит название файла, который нужно создать. Если в директории уже есть файл с таким же названием, то нужно удалить его и создать новый. Как реализовать удаление?

```
string a, b;
cout << "File name: ";
cin >> a;
if (FileExist(a))
{
    cout << "File already exists! Delete it? (Y, N) ->";
    cin >> b;
    if (b == "N" || b == "n")
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (b == "Y" || b == "y")
    {
        //удалить существующий файл
    }
}
else
{
        ofstream testfile(a.c_str());
        cout << "File created!\n";
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove

Comment: Можно POSIX-функциями типа `unlink`, можно стандартными из [`filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove), только вот у меня ощущение, что вы хотите не просто удалить... Иначе зачем создавать файл, если его нет? В чем ваша полная, так сказать, задача?

Comment: @Harry далее файл наполняется строками с текстом и обрабатывается определённым образом. Результат обработки выносится в отдельный файл.

Comment: Тогда зачем вам его удалять?

Comment: @Harry да я уже тоже об этом задумался. Переделал на то, чтобы программа просто предлагала ввести другое название.

Comment: Вы можете просто перезаписать существующий файл.